# Condition for three mutually perpendicular planes in 3D Geometry.

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

Let us consider three mutually perpendicular planes
$l_ix+m_iy+n_iz=p_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, where $l_i,m_i,n_i$ are direction cosines of the normals to the planes.    Since these three planes are mutually perpendicular, we have
$l_il_j+m_im_j+n_in_j=0$ for $i\neq j$.   Also we can say that $l_i^2+m_i^2+n_i^2=1$ for $i=1,2,3$.

How can I get the following relation from the above conditions:
$$l_1m_1+l_2m_2+l_3m_3=0$$ etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given condition implies $$A^TA=\left(\begin{matrix}
l_1&m_1&n_1\\l_2&m_2&n_2\\ l_3&m_3&n_3
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
l_1&l_2&l_3\\m_1&m_2&m_3\\ n_1&n_2&n_3
\end{matrix}\right)=I.$$ This implies $A^T=A^{-1}$ and hence
$$
AA^T=I.
$$ Then try to compute $(1,2)$-th entry of $AA^T$ (and others, too.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your answer@Song

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope it was helpful.